# Weblogic 12C error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jms.common.ResourceAllocationException

Tags: classpath, weblogic12c

I am facing this issue on my WebLogic 12 C, where an application gives this error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jms.common.ResourceAllocationException
```

The jar for the above class is wlclient.jar and it's not included in my application and I checked the managed server classpath ,it's not included there as well.

Funny thing is if I try adding the wlclient.jar in the setDomainEnv.sh as PRE_CLASSPATH hoping it will pick up the jar , I get the below error and managed server fails to start

```
<30-Mar-2019, 5:49:50,757 PM GMT> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000386> <Server subsystem failed. Reason: A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on weblogic.iiop.IIOPClientService

A MultiException has 2 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on weblogic.iiop.IIOPClientService

        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:391)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:232)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2020)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ORBHelper.<clinit>(ORBHelper.java:158)
        at weblogic.iiop.IIOPClientService.initialize(IIOPClientService.java:129)
        at weblogic.iiop.IIOPClientService.start(IIOPClientService.java:195)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot change <isServer>
        at weblogic.kernel.KernelStatus.setIsThinIIOPClient(KernelStatus.java:164)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.<clinit>(WLInitialContextFactory.java:26)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.ORBHelper.<clinit>(ORBHelper.java:158)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<30-Mar-2019, 5:49:50,825 PM GMT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FAILED.>
<30-Mar-2019, 5:49:50,825 PM GMT> <Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000383> <A critical service failed. The server will shut itself down.>
<30-Mar-2019, 5:49:50,827 PM GMT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to FORCE_SHUTTING_DOWN.>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found if I add the classpath fully like below then the managed server gave error on startup
,

```
PRE_CLASSPATH="${DOMAIN_HOME}/lib/wlclient.jar"
export PRE_CLASSPATH
```

But if I add the classpath as below , then it worked.

```
PRE_CLASSPATH="${DOMAIN_HOME}/lib/"
export PRE_CLASSPATH
```